# How can i calculate left and top position of Drag preview in React DnD?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am using React DnD for drag and drop in my application. [React DnD](https://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/examples-drag-around-custom-drag-layer.html)

I need to know how to implement Drag preview and position it while dragging.